# Prevent Excel to automatically "Wrap text" in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, cells, cell-format, word-wrap

Let's say we have a spreadsheet with all rows having the same default height.

In a cell, let's write `Hello` <kbd>ALT+ENTER</kbd> `World`. I indeed sometimes need to enter multi-line text in a cell, to write some long notes, etc.

Then this cell will **automatically** have the `Wrap text` button enabled (in the Home Ribbon menu), and this specific row will **automatically** have its height increased.

**How to disable this automatic `Wrap text`?** without having to manually click on `Wrap text` again to disable it?

---

See also (linked questions without a perfect solution for this problem):

- [How do I permanently disable Wrap Text?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-permanently-disable-wrap-text/22382c94-f02f-49ab-85ce-b128a0f1bff5)
- [How to disable auto Wrap Text in Excel](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-disable-auto-wrap-text-in-excel/5354862c-948a-4c38-9a7e-acae78f3e14c)
- [MS Excel 2010: Stop wrap text when pasting](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/cells/stop_wrapping2010.php)
- [Disable auto wrap text on excel 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/510e9b73-c821-44ba-992a-8ea2e1f4405b/disable-auto-wrap-text-on-excel-2010)
- [Disable wrap text?](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/758441-disable-wrap-text.html)
- [Turning off automatic text-wrapping](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/turning-off-automatic-text-wrapping.63972/)

Comment: I believe if you type <ALT+ENTER>, then Excel assumes you want to wrap text in the cell since you are specifying more than one line of text in it. You could always write a macro with a Worksheet Change for format the cell you just typed in as you want it to be.

Comment: I reviewed a [late answer](https://superuser.com/a/1766268/) that should be upvoted and accepted for future visitors.

Answer (score 7):

#### Set Fixed Row Height(s)

---

In order to stop row  heights from increasing to accommodate content containing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> line breaks you can set the row height(s) to a fixed value.

<sub>**Row Height: `Fixed Value`**  *vs.*  **`Default`**</sub>
[image]

#### Instructions

---

1. Select the row(s) whose height you want to lock
2. Open the `Row Height` dialog using one of the following approaches:  <sub><sup>*See images that follow*</sup></sub>
    A.  **Ribbon Bar:**  Select `Home` **>** `Format` **>** `Row Height`   
    B.  **Mouse:**  `Right-click` row(s) **>** `left-click` `Row Height`   
    C.  **Keyboard:**  <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
3. Choose `OK` to accept the prepopulated row height or set a numeric value of your choice then click **"OK"**  <sub><sup>***** *See* **NOTES** *Below*</sup></sub>

#### Notes

---

**`ROW HEIGHT` Dialog Box**   *( Instructions: Step 3 )*

- *With a **single row** selected, the* `Row Height` *dialog box will always have the* `Row height` *field **prepopulated** with the row's **current height***.
- *With **multiple rows** selected, the field will be prepopulated **only** if all have **identical heights**.*
- *Any time the field is **prepopulated**, one can immediately select* `OK` *(editing the field value becomes [optional]).*
- *In the case where the **heights** of multiple rows **do not match**, the* `Row height` *field will be **empty**. In that case a value **must be entered** before choosing* `OK`*. Otherwise, it will be equivalent to choosing* `CANCEL`*.*

[image][image]

#### Ribbon Bar Approach

---

<sub>`Home` **> `Format` > `Row Height`**</sub>
[image]

#### Right-Click Approach

---

<sub>**`Right-Click` row(s)**</sub>
[image]

#### Keyboard Approach

---

<sub>**<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**then <kbd>O</kbd>**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**then <kbd>H</kbd>**</sub>
[image]

Comment: Great example of when it is good to answer an old question! +10! No preexisting answers nailed it before you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us which verion of Office are you using?

If you have one of Professioanl Plus versions, you could try the Group Policy to disable this shortcut.

`User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Excel 2016 > Disable Items in User Interface > Custom, enable "Disable shotcut keys".`
Then enter following "[key],[modifier]" values:**13,16**.

[image]

For more information, please refer to "[Use Group Policy to disable user interface items and shortcut keys in Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179143(v=office.15)#disabling-shortcut-keys-by-using-virtual-key-codes)".

Comment: I still use 2007, and I don't see any Excel-related thing in `Group Policy` but it might be possible (I found some links about this) to add Group Policy for 2007, I'll try.

Comment: Anyway, what does your technique do? What does it disable exactly? If it disables the ALT+ENTER shortcut, then it's not what I'm looking for. I still want to be able to do ALT+ENTER to have multiline text. But I just want to avoid the automatic enabling of `Wrap text` button, and automatic change of height of a row.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl + A to select all cells in the current worksheet
2. Right click on any row number > Row Height > OK
3. Right click on any row number > Format Cells > Vertical Alignment = Top > OK

Comment: This doesn't work. As soon as you edit one of the cells with line breaks and hit enter they revert to the text wrapping.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén you are correct.  The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757084/) only works if all rows in the worksheet share identical heights.  If even one row is different, the solution fails.  This [answer by user1769377](https://superuser.com/a/1766268/1007040) works properly and should be upvoted to help future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent "Wrap Text" and changing row height is not your option, then VBA is quite a flexible solution.

Go to the sheet module first. Click on a sheet where you need to prevent words wrap, right click on it, select "View code".

[image: "View code"]

Depending on your needs, you may disable Text Wrap:

**a) entirely on the sheet**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cells.WrapText = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Target.Activate

End Sub
```

[image: VBA code to disable text wrap everywhere on the sheet]

**b) for specific column(s)**.
Here is a code that disable Text wrap in column "K":

```
If Target.Column = Range("K1").Column Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Target.WrapText = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Target.Activate
End If
```

[image: VBA code to disable text wrap for a specific column]

**c) for specific row(s)**.
Below, Text wrap is disabled for row 10:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.row = 10 Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Target.WrapText = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Target.Activate
End If

End Sub
```

[image: VBA code to disable text wrap for a specific row]

**d) for a range**.
In this example, that range is "B30:D100":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B30:D100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Target.WrapText = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Target.Activate
End If

End Sub
```

[image: VBA code to disable text wrap for a specific range]

---

Changing `Application.ScreenUpdating` from `True` to `False` in alignment with     `Target.Activate` make you stick to the cell you work with. Otherwise, the window will flicker because Excel enables wrapping by default, and then disables it after executing the code from the sheet module. This little trick helps stay focused.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method created when looking for a solution.  I'm not sure anyone would go to this effort but, it may give some an idea.  The workbook must be macro enabled (XLSM) and the code needs to be put into the worksheet.  Then, the cell(s) must be selected.  No disabling of actions such as screen updating were included. Enjoy.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'If even one cell in the selection has text wrapped, and
'if even one cell in the selection is changed
'then all cells in the selection have WrapText turned off
'Intersect Logic Source
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337008/excel-vba-run-macro-automatically-whenever-a-cell-is-changed
'Modified to prevent Wrap Text from being enabled when cell becomes dirty
'
'Range.WrapText property short description
'  It matters not how many cells in the range contain data, if any
'  if Me.Range("A1:B3").WrapText =
'     True:  All cells are wrapped
'     False: No cell is wrapped
'     Null:  at least one, but not all, cells are wrapped
On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine
   Dim lngRow1 As Long
   Dim lngRow2 As Long
   Dim lngCol1 As Long
   Dim lngCol2 As Long
   Dim rngSelected As Range

   'of course, these values would most likely be determined
   lngRow1 = 1
   lngRow2 = 3
   lngCol1 = 1
   lngCol2 = 2

'  The example demonstrates two formats, for "A1:B3", the first fixed and the second calculated
'  The intersect could, of course, consist of a single cell ("A2")
   If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'I'm unsure how this line helps
   Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop

   Set rngSelected = Selection         'Reselect their selection
   Me.Range(Cells(lngRow1, lngCol1), Cells(lngRow2, lngCol2)).Select
   With Selection
      If .WrapText = False Then
         GoTo ExitRoutine
      Else
         .WrapText = False
      End If
   End With
ExitRoutine:
   Application.EnableEvents = True    're-enable the events
   rngSelected.Select
   Set rngSelected = Nothing
   Exit Sub
ErrorRoutine:
   MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
   Resume ExitRoutine
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an answer:

The "Format Cells" dialog, i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> has an Alignment tab, where you find `[x] Wrap Text`...

To set or Reset that option for the entire sheet; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and remove/set `[x] Wrap Text`

This **might** help...

I can imagine that you have `Wrap Text` enabled for any adjacent cell when the "problem" occurs.

Comment: Sadly no, it doesn't work. You can try and set all cells (CTRL A) to "Wrap text" unchecked. Then go in any cell. Write `Hello <ALT+ENTER> World`, and you'll see the "Wrap text" will come again, automatically, for this cell.